# Using cURL to send POST data

Tags: php, forms, curl

Have form data that is to be sent to our email marketing service database (using cURL). Upon receipt of the data, it bounces back a confirmation page.

The problem is the confirmation page displays above the page that has the form on it. How do I get the confirmation page to render on its own? I believe the problem lies in the cURL script I am using, but can't figure it out.

**cURL code:**

```
    if ($validForm) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://oi.vresp.com?fid=2b68154d4e');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "first_name=$first_name&last_name=$last_name&email_address=$email_address&company_name=$company_name&cust_group=$cust_group");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` so that `curl_exec()` returns the data and you can choose what to do with it?

Comment: I am unsure how to implement the code you mentioned. Tried the code below, and now upon submitting the data, no confirmation page appears, it simply returns to the form page.
` if ($validForm) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://oi.vresp.com?fid=2b68154d4e');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "first_name=$first_name&last_name=$last_name&email_address=$email_address&company_name=$company_name&cust_group=$cust_group");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
  }`

Comment: Just wanted to update...I fixed the above issue by adding "exit();" at the end of the above code.